# How to loop an image to represent a number

Tags: laravel-5

i was able to display repuations in a tab but i want an image to represent the reputation number.

```
  <i class="fa fa-star-half-o"></i>  {{$artists->reputations}} </a></li>
```

For instance if the reputation is 5 i want an image to repeat 5 times,
if the reputation is 1 i want the image to repeat once and so on.

the image is located in my 'assets/images' folder
i tired doing something like this below

```
   <?php 
     $j = artists->reputations;
     @for($j=1;$j<=5;$j++)
     <i class="fa fa-star-half-o"></i>  <img src="assets/images/star.png" style="height:60px;"></a></li>

    ;?>
```

Comment: it's not working... i need help on it

Comment: What exactly isn't working ? you need to be specific here.

Comment: am always getting 5 images even if the reputation value is 3

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting `$j` in your loop condition.
So you always get 5 images. 
it should be looking like this if you only want 3 stars if `$artists->reputations = 3`.

```
<?php
$j = artists->reputations;
for($i=1;$i<=$j;$i++){
 <i class="fa fa-star-half-o"></i>  <img src="assets/images/star.png"style="height:60px;"></a></li>
}
?>
```

Comment: If this is your actual code i would recommend using clearer variable names. It helps a lot finding such errors.